# Commenting out glfwWindowHint() makes code functional (OpenGL with GLFW), why?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

sorry I had a bit of trouble with the proper name for this question, however I've run into a roadblock and I'd like to at least be informed as to the source.

I've been trying to learn to learn openGL and I'm following this tutorial:
[open.gl](http://open.gl)

**Lines in question:**

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
```

While following through the tutorial I got an access violation exception in my code. Only after I commented out the following lines was I able to get the program working as the tutorial says it should have worked the first time. The tutorial states the following about the commented out lines:

"You'll immediately notice the first three lines of code that are only relevant for this library. It is specified that we require the OpenGL context to support OpenGL 3.2 at the least. The GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE option specifies that we want a context that only supports the new core functionality."

My thought was that perhaps my drivers do not support OpenGL 3.2 or higher since when I commented out the **lines in question** my program ran fine. *However*, I downloaded a software called GPU caps viewer. When the software scanned my hardware it said that both my NVIDIA GeForce GT 540M and HD Graphics 3000 support OpenGL 4.3. So I'm very confused as to the source of my problem, **what I am doing wrong, or is this a hardware issue?**

Here are snapshots of GPU CAPS and NVIDIA PORTAL: [2 pictures on imgur](http://imgur.com/U7S8Khh&MTKwgKT)

**Doesn't Work:**

```
#include "stdafx.h"  //necessary headers in here


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
glfwInit();

glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "OpenGL", nullptr, nullptr); // Windowed
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
}
glfwTerminate();
return 0;
```

}

**Works:**

```
#include "stdafx.h" //necessary headers in here


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
glfwInit();
/**
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);
**/
GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "OpenGL", nullptr, nullptr); // Windowed
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
}
glfwTerminate();
return 0;
```

}

**Header File**

```
#pragma once
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <glew.h>

#include "targetver.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

#define GLFW_INCLUDE_GLU
#include <glfw3.h>
```

One last thing that came to mind, when I go to my NVIDIA control panel it shows Visual Studio 2013 only as using Intel HD 3000 graphics card. It doesn't give me an option to use my GeForce graphics with it, could this be the issue?

**EditOne:** 
I tried running my Visual Studio 2013 through windows explorer by right clicking on it and choosing "Run with graphics processor..." but to no avail.

I appreciate you looking through my question to help me solve it, and if you had this question yourself I hope it helped you solve your issue.

Comment: Your intel hd 3000 supports **only OGL 3.1 on Windows** and 3.3 on Linux/Mac OS (according to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_HD_and_Iris_Graphics). Try changing to 3.1 and leave forward comp commented and check out if it works. You might also want to try to start binary file (compiled with 3.2/3.3 version) not through Visual Studio, but go to it in Windows Explorer, right mouse on it, and run it using nvidia graphics card (this card should support at least OGL 4.0).

Comment: Okay, I tried running it through windows explorer with my Nvidia card but it still didn't work and the exception was still thrown. How can I change my use of OpenGL to only 3.1 and not 3.2, sorry but I'm very new to this as you can tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actual cause of the problem (as confirmed by OP) were out-of-date and/or not fully featured drivers. This is yet again a reminder that in case of OpenGL problems the first course of action should always be to upgrade to the latest version of the graphics drivers, *obtained directly from the GPU maker's download site.*

Two reasons for this:

1. OEM drivers usually lag a significant amount of releases behind the GPU vendors.
2. much more important: The drivers installed through Windows update are stripped of propper OpenGL support by Microsoft for reasons only known by Microsoft.

---

To make a long story short: Your program is probably going to get an OpenGL context for the Intel HD graphics which lacks the requested OpenGL capabilities. Thus when setting these GLFW windows hints the window creation fails and since your program does not check for this error it will try to use that window, which of course will cause trouble.

What should you do? *First and foremost add error checks!*
Here's an example how you can deal with the window creation failing:

```
GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(
     800,
     600,
     "OpenGL",
     nullptr,
     nullptr);
if( !window ) {
    print_some_error_message();
    exit(-1);
}
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
```

Next you want to force the system to use the NVidia card. Don't do that "launch through explorer run on NVidia BS"; say you ship your program to someone else? Do you want to put that burden onto them? Or how about you, when you want to debug it?

Do it properly: Tell the system that you want to run on the NVidia hardware in a Optimus configuration. Simply link the following into your program:

```
extern "C" {
    _declspec(dllexport) DWORD NvOptimusEnablement = 0x00000001;
}
```

The best place to put this would be right beside your program's main function, i.e. in your case

```
#include "stdafx.h"  //necessary headers in here

extern "C" {
    _declspec(dllexport) DWORD NvOptimusEnablement = 0x00000001;
} 

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    …
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, I did exactly as you mentioned above and placed the `extern "C"` snippet and it still throws an access violation in the same place. Right before `while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)){`, after adding an error check as you recommended (thank you) I can see that in fact, glfw is not creating the window at all. I will add my header file just in case something might be wrong there, but I doubt it.

Comment: @BryantheLion: I just saw that you're asking for a "forward compatibility profile". Forward capability is largely a no-op for 3.2 and later core profiles. While not necessarily a show stopper I suggest you remove setting that hint and try again.

Comment: So are you saying that commenting out those lines or not including them in my code will not have any adverse effects on the program in the future? Because that is mostly what I am worried about.

Comment: @BryantheLion: I was referring only to the forward compatibility profile flag. The other flags make sense of your program has definitive requirements on the OpenGL profile and thus are recommended. What really surprises me is, that adding the NvOptimusEnablement flag didn't do the trick. One suggestion: Did you update the NVidia drivers to their latest version (downloaded from the NVidia website and not through Windows Update)?

Comment: No, I didn't go directly to the Nvidia website, I went to the Asus website (my computer is an Asus) and I checked the drivers there. I found the same ones so I didn't change them, then I tried to update through windows device manager and windows said I had the latest version. I'll do what you said and check the Nvidia website then I'll let you know.

Can you specify to me which is the forward compatibility profile flag please?

Comment: Hey! I went to the **NVidia** website and I updated my drivers from there and wallah it works! Can you just add that to your answer to make it easier for someone to find out what I had to do in case they have this question too, thank you, let me know when you've done it so I can accept your answer.

Comment: @BryantheLion:  I think `GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT` is pretty much a give away. So I suggest to remove only (and only) the call `glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);`

Comment: Yea, I had done that, but it still didn't work before that, it was solved by your recommendation of updating my drivers through NVidia and not windows.

Comment: @BryantheLion: Updated my answer: Please read the update, since it might give you surprising information (mostly about Microsoft being, well Microsoft).

Comment: Thank you. I would upvote but I don't have the reputation yet. Have a good day!

Comment: There is also a GLFW CMake option for `NvOptimusEnablement`.